# The reason of using ''temp'' variables?

Tags: python

The question I'm asking is why do we use temporary variables after taking an input? For example: In the code down below, we've requested a 'num' from the customer. Then we've changed into it a 'temp'. Why don't we simply continue with 'num'? I can't see any aim into changing it a different variable. Why don't the code work if we don't make this swap? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you did modify `num` then how would you implement the check `if num == sum:`?

Comment: Think of it as an auxiliary variable that may temporarily store the same value of another but will change in time to accomplish your business logic. At the same time, you want the other variable to remain static.

Comment: Oh that makes sense :D I'm totally new to programming. Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name because that will shadow the built-in [sum](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sum) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is beacause in the while cycle in the last row you change the value of temp so if instead of temp you use num you will change its value and in the if else statement you can't compare the sum with the input number.